# Как аллоцировать неизменяемые поля класса, использующие динамическую аллокацию вместе с самим классом используя 1 вызов аллокатора

Tags: c++, c++17, malloc

Есть класс

```
class A
{
public:
...
private:
    std::string field1;
    std::string field2;
};
```

Этот класс всегда аллоцируется на куче, его поля после создания никак не именяются. Как сделать так, чтоб класс и поля выделились за одну аллокацию. Думаю эта проблема решается с помощью передачи пользовательского аллокатора, возможно есть готовая реализация?

Comment: Если они не меняются, то почему там не `std::string_view`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , потому что класс A владеет строками, просто после аллокации они не изменяются

Comment: Ему же не нужно будет их удалять, если они будут в том же блоке памяти. Там нечем владеть.

Answer (score -1):

Вообще тут зависит от контекста использования, если все строки хранятся в bss области (всегда и полностью заданы через двойные кавычки "" и не строятся в программе), можно в классе хранить `std::string_view` - аллокаций вообще не будет:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    A(const char* a, const char* b) : field1(a), field2(b) {}
...
private:
    std::string_view field1;
    std::string_view field2;
};

// ...

A a("Строка 1", "Строка 2");
```

Если по каким-то причинам нужно хранить в одном месте обе строки в принципе можно заменить `std::string` на `const char[size]`, а `size` передавать через шаблонный параметр.

Что-то вроде этого:

```cpp
template<size_t size_1, size_t size_2>
class A
{
public:
...
private:
    const char field1[size_1 + 1]; // +1 на символ null
    const char field2[size_1 + 1];
};
```

В таком случае все поля будут располагать в одном месте единым блоком памяти, а взаимодействовать со строками так же можно через `std::string_view`.

**Ключевой недостаток:** требуется чтобы размеры строк были известны на этапе компиляции программы.

Если размеры не известны на стадии компиляции можно сделать как-то так:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    A(std::string a, std::string b)
        : field1(new char(a.size() + b.size() + 2)),
          field2(field1 + a.size() + 1) {
        std::memmove(field1, a.data(), a.size() + 1);
        std::memmove(field2, b.data(), b.size() + 1);
    }
    ~A() { if(field1) delete field1; }
...
private:
    const char* field1 = nullptr;
    const char* field2;
};
```

Объект с двумя указателями оставляем на стэке, блок памяти с двумя строками разделённые null-символом выделяется в куче одной аллокацией.

Comment: Третий вариант - ближе всего к тому что просил автор, но в вопросе все-таки просят и строки и `A` в одном блоке памяти. Плюс нет смысла руками звать `new`, когда есть `std::string` - из-за этого ваш класс, например, не выдерживает копирование: `A x("f","g"), y(x);` = краш.